# How to apply filter in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular and would like to apply filter to this JSON  to only get "place" objects.

```
   {
  "places": {
    "live": "true",
    "status": "default",
    "place": [
      {
        "-name": "Test",
        "-url": "http://myurl"
      },
      {
        "-name": "Test",
        "-url": "http://myurl"
      },
      {
        "-name": "Test",
        "-url": "http://myurl"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I was thinking of applying filter with something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="place in places | filter:{place:'http'}">
```

This is clearly wrong . Is there a way to apply filter to only get "place" objects

Comment: shouldn't places be a JSON object not XML?  I haven't seen anywhere in Angular where a model is defined in XML, could you point to how this is bound to your scope?

Comment: Its a JSON object. Sorry should have made it clear

Comment: this is unclear; are you trying to get the items of the `place` array, or only the `-url` field values?

Comment: To only repeat *place-objects* just use: `ng-repeat="place in places.place"`. No filter needed.

Comment: Yup other option if you have an array of "places" as well would be to iterate over item in places the for display pass the item.place array to some function that returns a string.  You should probably edit your question again to show 1 full data set then 2 what you would want to show.

Comment: @Yoshi .ng-repeat="place in places.place" would not work since places is the array and not place. Place is the actual object and not  a list

Comment: @Milligran The data you showed, clearly shows `places.place` to be an array. If what you showed does not include the complete structure of the data (as it is stored in the `$scope`) noone will be able to help you, as one would have to guess the structure. I think, either posting your whole code or adding a fiddle/plunker would be most helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-repeat="place in places.place">
```

should work I think